# Is there a way to have optional parameters in a javascript function when calling the script from Rhino?

Tags: javascript, rhino

I have written a javascript project which makes extensive use of default parameters, for example:

```
function hello(x = true){
    ...
}
```

Now I want to call my code from the command line. I have tried using Rhino, Nashorn and Node but they all throw errors when encountering default parameters. In Rhino the error is:

```
js: "resource.js", line 6: missing ) after formal parameters
js: function hello(x = true){
js: ..................^
js: "resource.js", line 1: Compilation produced 1 syntax errors.
```

Is there some way I can call my project from the command line without having to rewrite all my code to get rid of default arguments?

Thanks

EDIT: after updating node.js to version 8 from version 4, this works. I will use node.js but I still don't know if this is possible on rhino.

Comment: Which versions did you use? Especially node knows how to deal with defaults since a long time.

Comment: I am using rhino 1.7, and it turns out my ubuntu installed an older version of node - v4.2.6. So updating node does the trick, thanks! I would still prefer using rhino if possible since I have a lot of global variables and node would require me to redo all that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You always have a way to copy the behavior of default arguments but it won't as readable as with a newer version of javascript.

The straightforward way of doing it **if you only have one argument** would be an `undefined` check inside your function, *i.e.*:

```
js> function hello(x){
  >   if (x === undefined) x = 5;
  >   return x;
  > }
js> hello()
5
js> hello(42)
42
```

On the other hand, **if your function contains more arguments** I would recommend you to use an object as input and then check for an `undefined` value, as above:

```
js> function hello(args){                              
  >   if (args.x === undefined) args.x = 5;     
  >   return args.x + "-" + args.y;
  > }
js> hello({y: 12})   
5-12
js> hello({x: 1, y: 42})
1-42
```